# How to reduce number of lines in jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I am learning jquery, and need your help. I want to reduce the number of codes here:

I have three buttons on `navbar`. `cart`, `.account`, `.help`. If I click on `cart`, I want to hide dropdown menu for `account` and `help`. Same goes for other buttons. Here is the jquery code, I have written so far! Could anyone help me to reduce the number of lines of code?

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(".cart").click(function(){
    $(".cart .dropdown-menu").show();
    $(".account .dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(".help .dropdown-menu").hide();
});

$(".account").click(function(){
    $(".cart .dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(".account .dropdown-menu").show();
    $(".help .dropdown-menu").hide();
});

$(".help").click(function(){
    $(".cart .dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(".account .dropdown-menu").hide();
    $(".help .dropdown-menu").show();
});
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>madison square market</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="pull-right">
            <ul>
              <li class="cart dropdown">
                <h3>cart &#x25BE;</h3>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>View Cart</li>
                  <li>Saved Carts</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="account dropdown">
                <h3>account &#x25BE;</h3>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>View Account</li>
                  <li>Check Order Status</li>
                  <li>Sign in</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="help dropdown">
                <h3>help &#x25BE;</h3>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>FAQs</li>
                  <li>Return Policy</li>
                  <li>Shipping Info</li>
                </ul>
              </li>             
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
    </div>

    <div class="supporting">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>recent arrivals</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/madison-square-market/carrots.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/madison-square-market/cauliflower.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/madison-square-market/peppers.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="supporting">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>popular produce</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/madison-square-market/potatoes.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/madison-square-market/onions.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/2/madison-square-market/tomatoes.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>follow</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Twitter</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to post this question in http://codereview.stackexchange.com. It specifically is a site for this. Here it is just another "uninteresting question".

Comment: But I am not asking for code review. I am pretty sure there are better ways out there to handle such things.

Comment: Have you tried delegate events approach in Jquery... This allows you to decrease the code to some extent?

Comment: Well today is my first day, so I will try now

Comment: You should the event delegation section in here : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Hello You can reduce it like this

```
$('.dropdown-menu').prev("h3").on("click",function(){
   $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
   $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").show();    
});
```